# How can I insert a server side handlebars partial using javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

Im building a web application that has some server side layouts and partials. I'm trying to insert partials into the dom using javascript depending on which button the user clicks. Below I've included a simple example that shows what I **want** to do, obviously it doesn't work. I know you can registerPartials by writing them in the same document and so on, but is there a similar function to be able to use a partial from the server? I wish i could call registerPartial and just pass it the url to the partial or something. For the below example, assume the following folder structure, and that I've registered the partials folder accordingly:

```
-web
   L views
      L partials
         L edit-user.handlebars
         L reset-pass.handlebars
      L main.handlebars
```

**code:**

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

    var edit = {{> edit-user}};

    var resetPass = {{> reset-pass}};

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#editMenuAction").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log(html);
            $("#adminChangesDiv").html(edit);
        });
      
      $("#resetPassMenuAction").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log(html);
            $("#adminChangesDiv").html(resetPass);
        });
    });
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://builds.handlebarsjs.com.s3.amazonaws.com/handlebars-v3.0.3.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav id="menu" class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!--<div class="navbar-header navbar-brand" id="beingEdited">Admin</div>-->
        <ul id="menu-items" class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li id="editMenuAction" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit this user's profile."><a>Edit Profile <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></a></li>
                <li id="resetPassMenuAction" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Reset user's password."><a>Reset Password</a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>

<div id="changesDiv">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Handlebars won't do http requests for you. I think you have three options:

You could write a small utility function that requests the template, compiles it, and uses it.

Or, if your templates are precompiled, you could consider using requirejs or a similar tool to dynamically load the script.

What I do on my site is precompiled the Handlebars and bundle those functions into my js files which use them, eliminating any latency between when data is ready to be rendered and the actual render.